# Jsoup parse: getting text from Element not working in Android

Tags: android, json, web-scraping, jsoup, wikipedia-api

I'm parsing wikipedia in Android using Jsoup. I want to get "Sección Sur-Norte" inside this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="thumb tright">
    <div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;">
         <a href="//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cheops-Pyramide.png" class="image">
             <img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cheops-Pyramide.png/300px-Cheops-Pyramide.png" width="300" height="227" class="thumbimage" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cheops-Pyramide.png/450px-Cheops-Pyramide.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cheops-Pyramide.png/600px-Cheops-Pyramide.png 2x">
         </a>
         <div class="thumbcaption">
              <div class="magnify">
                <a href="/wiki/Archivo:Cheops-Pyramide.png" class="internal" title="Aumentar">
                    <img src="//bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.23wmf10/skins/common/images/magnify-clip.png" width="15" height="11" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
               Sección Sur-Norte. <--> Text I want to scrape
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting selected selected 'thumbinner' as an Element. I'm trying to get 'Sección Sur-Norte' by doing:

```
Elements thumbCaption = thumbinner.select("div[class*=thumbcaption]");
Element myThumbCaption = thumbCaption.first();
Log.d("", "Thumbcaptions number of elements: " + thumbCaption.size());
Log.d("", "MyThumbcaption: text:  " + aver.text());
```

But in logs I'm getting that thumbcaption has 8 elements (all 'thumbcaption' elements in document after that point). And I'm getting than MyThumbcaption text is all text in document after that).

How could I scrape 'Sección Sur-Norte' only?

---

MORE INFO:

I'm getting thumbinner element from img name by doing:

```
Elements imgs = doc.select("img[src*=" + name + "]"); 
Element img = imgs.first(); // Image selected
Element parentCaption = img.parent();
Element thumbinner = parentCaption.parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ownText()` method on the thumbcaption div. It gets the text owned by the element only, ignoring any text that is owned by its child elements.

Example:

```
Element myThumbCaption = thumbCaption.first();
System.out.println(myThumbCaption.ownText());
```

Should output:

```
Sección Sur-Norte.
```

You can read more about this method [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29).

Comment: Not working. It's incredible but that is getting an empty String. I'm starting to think Jsoup doesn't work very well in Android!

Comment: It's working for me, but only when I use the HTML that you have supplied. If you parse the real URL which I assume that you do, the `thumbCaption.first()` will return the wrong element. What you want is to use `thumbCaption.get(1)` to get the correct element.
Also note that you should be aware that sites respond different to different clients, thus it might be a good idea to set the user agent differently when connecting to the URL.